# Ionic framework with AngularJs : Can a modal have the same controller as the view that launches the modal?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to build out a multistep form for a complex object. I use the modal to section out parts of the form. The Ionic examples I could find, appear to assign a different controller to the modal. I would like to keep the view plus all the modals it launches, all of them associated with one controller. Is that possible? I tried assigning to the modal view ng-controller="viewCtrl" where viewCtrl is also the controller of the starting view that launches the modal, but it appears to hang chrome with a high CPU which subsequently necessitates killing the chrome tab.(some sort of cyclic effect by calling the same controller??) 
Your advice/insight would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your modal is a directive.
I also assume that you have it placed inside the view (controller scope).

If the above are correct than the directive inherits the $scope properties and methods from the parent controller (a general thing in angular), unless your directive has an isolated scope (if you have the scope property in the directive set to anything but false).

If your directive has an isolated scope you can still pass data from the parent using attributes on the directive. If you want to pass something from the directive to the parent you can use $emit.
You can also access the parent from the directive using $parent but I would suggest against it.

Comment: +1 and thanks for your response, your comments helped turn my attention to scope inheritance. Iconic framework implements modal as a service which, it tuns out, has an option for scope inheritance. I will add the specifics in a separate answer for future reference by others.

Comment: @CAT From what you've explained, I get the $scope part, but how would I set the controller that I want to be the modal controller (since I want a different controller than the controller that called the modal).

Comment: @RafaelEyng I'm not sure if I get what you mean but if you want your modal directive to have it's own controller you just use the "controller: MyModalController" property when you create you're directive. You could also just add ng-controller="MyController" on the root element of the directive and create that controller ... it's basically the same thing. If this is not what you're asking maybe create a new question with more details, I'll be glad to help if I can.

Comment: @CAT I've downloaded an Ionic template and started developing my app on top of it. It has a login modal, that are called using: `$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(url, {scope: $scope}).then(/* ... */)`. I have some views that I want to show as a normal part of my app and also use the same view as a modal in another part of the app. When using it these views as non-modal views, I'm using it, with browserify, `angular.module('app.customer, []).controller('CustomerCtrl', require('./CustomerController'))` to set the controller. But when using it as a modal (calling as in first snippet), the ...

Comment: controller of my modal is the same controller of the view that called the modal. So, I would need to set the modal's controller to be the CustomerCtrl (in my example above). So I don't understand how to use the `ng-controller="CustomerController` to set it when it is a modal, since I don't set it also when it is not a modal. I don't think that my question is clear, and I'm sorry for that. It is a consequence of how confused I am about this.

Comment: @RafaelEyng I don't have experience with Iconic framework but from what I noticed in the docs the $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(url, {scope: $scope}) part allows you to specify on which $scope to build the modal scope, it basically creates a child of the $scope you specified which is exactly what you are saying that it's the $scope that you triggered the modal from. You will need to point to your CuromerCtrl scope. Depending on your structure you could either specify that scope as a $parent/$child scope or you could emit an event to your controller ...

Comment: .. and in your CustomerCtrl you just listen for that event and initiate the modal there on it's $scope.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll as a question if needed and link it from here.

Comment: @CAT It seems that you ' You will need to point to your CustomerCtrl scope' phrase is the answer to what I need. Unfortunately, I don't understand how to do that. I don't see what exactly is the relation between the scope and the controller. What I need is the CustomerController to handle the user interaction with my customer view (now appearing as a modal), but if I define a method with the same name both in my CustomerController (the modal), and in the parent controller, the one that gets called is the parent's, and I need the Customer's to be called.